# Short deck probability

Tags: probability

Short deck is remove 2-5 so 36 cards left.  A6789 is a straight.

What is the hand order and probability.

For example a flush is harder to make but a straight is easier.

Ideally post the equations for probability.

Answer (score 2):

Number of possible 5 card hands 376,992

```
               count    fraction  cumulative
straight flush    24  0.00006366  0.00006366            
quads            288  0.00076394  0.00082760
flush            480  0.00127324  0.00668449 
boat            1728  0.00458365  0.00541126   
straight        6120  0.01623377  0.02291826 
trips          16128  0.04278075  0.06569901 
2 pair         36288  0.09625668  0.16195569 
1 pair        193536  0.51336898  0.67532468 
high card     122400  0.32467532  1.00000000 
total         376992
```

A flush becomes harder than a boat.

Some sources say trips become harder than a straight but that is not what my numbers conclude.

I just ran [these equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). Please don't ask me to post the calculations.  They are in that link.  This site does not support Latex. There is a meta asking for support of [Latex](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/latex-commands-request-feature/229#229) that I encourage you to up vote.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Straight flush count of 24 is correct.  If you want to run 7 cards the please do so.

Comment: You are correct my apologies. I am trying 7 cards right now, but for me it is really difficult :/

Comment: Trips are harder than straight when you use 7 cards, but mostly because they turn into full houses very often.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru Turn into a full house has not germane.  There is a be nice policy so I will leave it here.

Comment: @paparazzo Not sure what you mean. I explained that when you add two more cards you see less trips because the new cards will pair the first five, in addition to adding more straights.